# How to go bact to login page from Axios interceptor?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I'm using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for making API requests. I have implemented a centralized [Interceptor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#interceptors) which is used by all the components to fetch the data.
All the components use this interceptor for including `token` in request header and then to send all api requests.
Now, in case of error in response I **want to redirect to login page.** For that I'm trying to set a flag in `Redux store` named `isTokenValid`. Idea is I'm going to set a `subscriber` to the `store` in `App.js` or `index.js` and as soon as flag is set to `false` I will redirect user to login page.
The issue is I am not able to access any functions I pass via `mapDispatchToProps` using `this.props.invalidToken()`.

- How to solve this issue?
- Is there any better approach

Answer (score 5):

You can use this as quick fix

```
if(error.response?.status === 401){
          localStorage.clear()
          window.location.href = "/login";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try these following steps in (vue-cli) :

1. in axios.js

   ```
    import Axios from 'axios'

    import router from '../router'  // use router/index.js path

    import store from 'store path'

    Axios.interceptors.response.use((res) => {
        return Promise.resolve(res);
    }, (error) => {
           if (error!= null && error.status == 401) {
            store.dispatch(call_to_your_store_action, pass_params_here);
            router.push({ // here is the redirect component OR USE window.location.href='/login'
                    path: '/login',  
                    name: 'login'  
                })

        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    })


    export default Axios
   ```
2. router/index.js

   ```
    import login from '@/components/login'

    const router = new Router({
            routes:[
                        {
                            path: '/login',
                            name: 'login',
                            component: login,

                        }
                    ]
            });

    export default router
   ```
3. in main.js

   ```
   import axios from './axios'  //step 1 path
   ```

Comment: that `store.dispatch...` came out of thin air, right? :))